# Why text-align:justify is making a large line space and how to correct them?

Tags: space, text-align, justify, white-framework

I'm writing a blog website and want to make the paragraph with text-align justified. However, It worked fine. However, there are also of white space between letters sometimes. Is there any way to correct it?

Comment: .par{text-align: justify}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.